# Metadata Equivalent of the System Permission "Connect Org to Customer 360 Data Manager"

Tags: salesforcedx, profile, metadata, xml

I'm currently experiencing the error:

> "You may not modify the permission Connect Org to Customer 360 Data Manager while editing a Standard Profile".

I've checked in the destination org that this is turned off anyway so I just decided to remove it. However, I cannot find the Admin Profile user permission metadata entry for this. I don't know what it's named and the xml entries are not that intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

Removing the ManageHubConnections userpermissions metadata block under the Admin.profile allowed me to deploy successfully.

```
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ManageHubConnections</name>
</userPermissions>
```