# Metadata Equivalent of the System Permission "Run Macros on Multiple Records"

Tags: salesforcedx, profile, metadata

I'm getting the following error when deploying profile Metadata:

> "You may not modify the permission Run Macros on Multiple Records while editing a Standard Profile"

I know I need to remove a `userPermissions` element from the XML file, but which one corresponds to "Run Macros on Multiple Records".

I'm aware that [Metadata Equivalent of the System Permission “Connect Org to Customer 360 Data Manager”](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/288419/102) is a very similar question. This is the same problem, but for a different permission name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it was the `BulkMacrosAllowed` user permission.

I removed the following from my Admin.profile-meta.xml file.

```
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>BulkMacrosAllowed</name>
</userPermissions>
```

It does raise the question of how we are supposed to do these name to label translations, but that is another question... [How can I map between a permission name in the API and the label shown in the UI?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/322148/102)