# How can I map between a permission name in the API and the label shown in the UI?

Tags: profile, metadata, permission-sets

I just [ran into an error](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/322146/102) when deploying a Profile that required knowing the mapping between the UI Label "Run Macros on Multiple Records" and it's corresponding API PermissionName of "BulkMacrosAllowed".

I was able to guess at that based on the metadata that was changing with the deployment. However, how can I find a more complete set of mappings between the API names and the UI labels?

The data is available in the HTML source, but that would be painful to extract.

[image: Setup showing App Permissions]

[image: HTML mapping between PermissionName and label]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one possible solution posted by SteveMo in [API Names of System and App Permissions?](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009BdJIAU).

I can use the field describe metadata from PermissionSet to map from the fields Name to its label.

*Images from [Steve's post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009BdJIAU).*

[image: PermissionSet fields shown by workbench]

[image: PermissionSet field metadata, including Label and Name]

I've posted an expanded set of mappings in [Mappings between Salesforce Permission Name and the Label](http://www.fishofprey.com/2020/10/mappings-between-salesforce-permission.html)

[image: Permission API Name to Label mappings]

Answer (score 1):

Step by step process to map between permission name and label

https://www.sfdcamplified.com/2021/09/challenge-map-between-salesforce-permissionname-and-label.html